# InputStream Room TypeConverter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, jakarta-mail, inputstream

I am trying to convert `InputStream` into `String` so I can save it to local database. I created type converter for that but I think that I am missing something.

```
@TypeConverter
fun toInputStream(value: String): InputStream = value.byteInputStream()

@TypeConverter
fun fromInputStream(inputStream: InputStream): String = inputStream.bufferedReader().use {
    it.readText()
}
```

I keep getting `FolderClosedIOException` because I am using `JakartaMail`. Basically, I can ready mail text and everything fine, but when I am trying to save `InputStream` to local DB, I keep getting this exception. I don't know if my type converter is wrong or error is somewhere else.

[image: Exception]

Comment: A Room `@Entity` should not have an `InputStream` as a property, any more than it should have a `Socket` as a property.

Comment: @CommonsWare How do you suggest me to save it then? Because I want to save InputStream so later I can download attachement into internal storage. Should I go for different approach?

Comment: "Because I want to save InputStream so later I can download attachement into internal storage" -- either you need to download the attachment *now*, or you need to save stuff in the entity that lets you *find* the attachment on the server later and make a fresh request. This is not significantly different than with any other network protocol, such as HTTPS: you need to make the request and process the result in real time.